# Magento2: How to separate quote?

Tags: cart, quote, quoteitem, cart-items

Like, I have 5 items in my Cart.

It means there is 1 row in **quote** table. Which contains parent ID.

And,  5 rows in **quote_item** which describe all 5 items.

I want separate 3 items from these 5 in another custom quote and need a separate quote for these 3 items.

Expected result:

I want 2 quotes,

1 have 2 items AND 3 items will assign to the newly created quote.

Help would be appreciated.